# Django: User profile seems to be preventing syncdb

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

After adding a user profile (called user info here) my models.py file wont syncdb. I get:`TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` and all the errors above that mention the models.py file or some file relating to it.

Models.py file:

```
def create_user_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_info, sender=User)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    pen_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    activated = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email + '-' + self.pen_name
```

Auth thing in settings.py:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'Knights.UserInfo'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/models.py", line 53, in <module>
    class Alert(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/models.py", line 55, in Alert
    for_user = models.ForeignKey()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error does not lie in your posted code. You've followed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) to the letter, so I would've been surprised if it did.

Instead, the error is found in your Alert class (models.py:55). `for_user = models.ForeignKey()` has to be `for_user = models.ForeignKey(User)` or `for_user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo)`, depending on which you prefer.

Your faulty code was trying to instantiate an instance of the class `ForeignKey`, which calls it's `__init__()` method. That method will have a declaration of something like

```
def __init__(self, other_model):
```

and thus the error message saying that you're missing one parameter. `self` gets passed implicitly, read up on the Python classes docs if you're interested.

Comment: Nice, but I would rather advise using `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`, because we are trying to achieve one-to-one relation, don't we? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: @Tadeck I'm assuming you're talking about the Alert.for_user attribute. The choice between a ForeignKey and a OneToOneField depends entirely on the use case, e.g. you might want multiple alerts for one user.

Comment: I missed that you were referring to `Alert` definition (you did not mention it by name, only by the number of the line), so I assumed you were referring to `UserInfo`, where `OneToOneField` is standard approach, used within the docs and should be really applied. In other words: I misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: @Tadeck Thanks for the feedback. I hope the text is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    pen_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    activated = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email + '-' + self.pen_name

    def create_user_info(self, **kwargs):
         u = kwargs["instance"]
         created = kwargs["created"]
         if not created:
            UserInfo(user=u).save()

post_save.connect(UserInfo.create_user_info, sender=User)
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a staticmethod decorator somewhere?

Comment: Could you explain this a bit (and why mine does not work). Sorry, I'm new to django.

Comment: Well looking at your stack trace, you might be missing a User in for_user = models.ForeignKey(User) on line 55 of your models.py